# Why is my p element in single.php not being implemented?

Tags: php, html, server-side

I work for this organization, Vibro, and I am website responsible. We have a sharing box with social icons on everyone of our articles. We want to add the text "del:" (Meaning share in norwegian) in front of the icons in the box. When I went into single.php and added a paragraph element with the text, the code won't be implemented.

Do you have any idea why, and how to fix it?

I've already tried: corrected syntax error, deleted cache and minified css, tried indenting with space and put the p element outside the ul. Does not work! Maybe the changes takes some time to be implemented, I made some changes earlier today that didn't go through before later.

Here's the code in single.php:

```
<div class="box-social">
<ul class="social social</ul>
<p>Del:</p>
<li>
<a class="circle-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="circle-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php the_title(); ?>&summary=&source="><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="circle-icon" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"> 
</i>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Trim down your code block to the necessary code

Comment: Do you mean the entire file? Or just the box?

Comment: It's hard to read your code block, so only include the code relevant to your question, not the entire script.

Comment: Read this and update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe you should detail exactly what you were trying to add inside it. you mentioned `<p>del:</p>` before the elements?

Comment: If your code isn't changing, this sounds entirely like a server side caching issue

Comment: If it isn't changing it's either a caching issue, or you aren't updating the file you thought you were. This is more of a server question. I'll give you some guidance for posting questions on this site. And, welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: [Please, do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) then **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Comment: Devon and Meshu: I have edited the code to only the essentials.

Comment: mcv: I only want to add a p element with the text: "del". zack:I cleared cache and minified css just 20 min ago. Can it be possible it takes some time to be updated. adpro: I checked, it is the right file.

Comment: I changed the code to just the essential and rewrote the title

Comment: I now also deleted typing errors and reformulated the question.

Comment: <p> tag inside a <ul> tag doesn't seem right. Insert the <p> before <ul> and then simply use CSS to work on the presentation.

Comment: Rolando: I'll try that

Comment: Rolando: It didn't change anything!

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided has invalid markup.
You can use something like this https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input to validate your html.

One issue with your code is `Element p not allowed as child of element ul in this context.`

I fixed the broken `<ul>` and moved the `<p>` before it.

```
<div class="box-social">
<p>Del:</p>
   <ul class="social social">
      <li>
         <a class="circle-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="circle-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php the_title(); ?>&summary=&source="><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="circle-icon" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried different indentation, still, I've heard it doesn't matter. The ul need classes "social social-add", you've deleted out "social-add".

Comment: @AlexanderMyrvold look at the code you pasted, it says `<ul class="social social</ul>`

Comment: Ops! My fault then. It's suppose to say social-add :)